# System Freeze and Crash (18.04) when running Python-Scripts on CUDA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, crash, cuda

When I execute python-scripts running on CUDA, my machine will freeze and then crash without displaying any error messages. The same scripts were executed without problems just 2 weeks ago, on the same device.

**Details**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- GPU GeForce GTX 2070 SUPER
- Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76 (tried other versions as well, e.g., 9 and 10.1, 10.2)
- Driver: NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03
- Python 3.6.9
- PyTorch 1.10.1+cu102
- Crash triggered by python package `sentence-transformers==2.2.2`
- Motherboard AMD-Ryzen-7-2700X

**Attempts to resolve issues**

- Reinstalled CUDA and NVIDA drivers (multiple times, different versions)
- Removed and reinstalled all python packages in virtual environment
- Updated BIOS drivers for AMD-Ryzen-7-2700X
- Disabled `Global C-state Control` in BIOS [as suggested here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/repeatable-system-freezes-under-gpu-load-with-threadripper-ubuntu-18-04/138237/11).
- Disabled `Core Performance Boost` in BIOS [as suggested here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/repeatable-system-freezes-under-gpu-load-with-threadripper-ubuntu-18-04/138237/11).
- Checked `syslog`, no trace of an error for the given time

I have no clue how to get more information about what the possible error could be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the power supply unit was damaged and the issue went away after replacing it.